# Disable scrollbar while splshpage loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script for splash/intro page loader

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#splash').fadeOut(500); 
    }, 6000); 
});
```

The script will hide the intro page after 6sec. But the problem is scrollbar stil visible and i want hide the scrollbar while the intro page onload for 6sec.

need advice... thank you

Comment: You might have an `overflow: scroll` rule in your css where the scrollbar appears at.. In that case, you need to change it to `hidden` or `auto`.

Answer (score 6):

make your

```
html, body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
$(function(){ setTimeout(function() { 

   $('#splash').fadeOut(500); }, 6000); 
   $(' html, body').css({overflow: 'auto'});

});
```

this will turn back the scroll on after 6s.

Comment: please accept my answer as correct if it suits your need. :)